# Examples of inner, nested, local and anonymous classes from JDK, JRE

Tags: java, inner-classes, anonymous-class, local-class

I find a very useful to read this question: [Java inner class and static nested class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70324/java-inner-class-and-static-nested-class?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa), but can't find there any example from Java. Could you provide me with real examples of using those classes from JDK, JRE?

Comment: One example could be the ArrayList implementation - java.util.ArrayList. It contains several inner classes implementing the java.util.Iterator interface. There are factory methods that return new instances of these inner classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nested classes (static inner) do not have a reference to outer context. Map#Entry is an example of such nested class -- it contains only key, value pair properties and by definition has no access to outer Map implementation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I also found a few examples in java.lang package: Character, ProcessBuilder, Thread; Other ones java.net.Proxy, java.util.ResourceBundle, java.util.Formatter, ...